# 1-to-1: Essential conversation topics

Tags: management

Simple question, with many differing answers:

**As a manager(of a office worker), What should a monthly check-in include / be about?**

Comment: Suggest rephrasing this to "*What should a monthly check-in include / be about?*" Asking for specific topics makes this more of a list question which is off-topic. Structured and comprehensive answers about the kinds of things that should be discussed *would* be on-topic and useful.

Comment: I agree, I have changed the question.

Comment: I'll respond with my manager's opinion (for which I completely agree). A one-on-one check-in should include whatever topic is important to the associate. Managers should have mechanisms to monitor associate progress (time-sheets, completed task lists, to do lists, monthly success  stories, etc..) but a one-on-one should be an opportunity for an associate to bring up the things that concern them. As a manager, try not to drive the meeting but rather listen to what is important to the associate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll try to provide a few tips or suggestions I personally follow.

- You should let this person talk about things he or she is happy about, or this person has concerns or problems with. I usually divide our 1-2-1s in the following categories: personal, people, projects and others.
- Document these conversations in a shared document only you two have access, and write the notes together. This is a great way of following-up on the different topics, both for you and your team member.
- Discuss about his or her career goals and how to get to those goals. In many companies, these goals are set in a yearly appraisal. Even though I strongly believe some goals are mid and long-term, make sure these goals are followed-up and updated periodically, and not just once a year.
- 70/30 rule. Your team member should be speaking 70% of the time, while you do it on the other 30%. Of course this is a guideline and it's not always like that.
- Use this space also to get to know your team member better. As you can see in the first item of this list, I suggest having a "personal" category.
- Probably obvious, but have the 1-2-1s in a private and safe environment (e.g. a meeting room).
- Tailor the 1-2-1 topics and frequency considering your team member's needs.

I hope this helps. Let me know if you have questions or doubts.

Comment: I'd appreciate if the user who downvoted my answer could provide some feedback, so I can also learn more about this topic. Thanks.

Comment: Not the downvoter, but it could be you agree the question is potentially off topic, yet you've answered (just sayin...)

Comment: I think the main point of this is that the employee should drive the meeting.  My own teams I ask to send me through an agenda a day or so before the meet (this could be 2-3 bullets, so shouldn't take more than a minute to put in an email), and allows me to see what's on their mind, if there is something related I want to talk about, and maybe do some prep if they are going to ask about something HR related.

Comment: Outstanding answer... the 70/30 rule is a great one.